# Drush 10, Drupal 9, views-bulk-operations:execute using entity:delete_action:node seems to work but won't save its changes

Tags: drush

I'm trying a command:
drush -vvv views-bulk-operations:execute -d deleteme_content entity:delete_action:node

where deleteme_content is a View with translations of entities that I want to delete.  The command appears to work and prints a success message but the content is not actually deleted.

I've traced all the way into drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Action/Plugin/Action/DeleteAction.php where I added some temporary logging messages and see in executeMultiple() that the desired entities are being changed in $this->tempStore.

So it looks to me like the changes are being made in tempStore but then not being "committed" to the permanent storage.  I have looked for a "commit" type option in both drush and the vbo-execute command for drush and don't see anything.

Can anyone provide a clue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report to a third-party project hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and therefore must be filed with its [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/views_bulk_operations) to get it fixed, not here with Drupal Answers. Thank you for your understanding. 

Comment: While it appears to be a bug I'm not entirely sure of that yet.  It's possible there's a usage nuance I'm missing which is why I'm asking for anyone with experience to chime in to either correct me or confirm it's a bug.